# Search an array for the specific value and return its key

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multidimensional array, which I want to search and returns its corresponding key so that I can again use the key and return more information from that corresponding array.

**This is what my array looks like**

```
$add_admin_menu_page = array();
$add_admin_menu_page[] = array('Dashboard', 'dashboard.php', 'dashboard');
$add_admin_menu_page[] = array('Posts', 'posts.php', 'posts');
$add_admin_menu_page[] = array('Comments', 'comments.php', 'comments');
$add_admin_menu_page[] = array('Tools', 'tools.php', 'tools');
```

**This is what am doing currently to make it work**

```
<?php
//global $add_admin_menu_page;
$page = "dashboard.php";
$key = array_search($page, $add_admin_menu_page);
var_dump($key);
?>
```

Above result outputs

> bool(false)

Comment: array_search() is __not__ recursive, however the comments on that docs page provide plenty examples of how to do a recursive array search

Comment: Let's me try the recursive way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example from [array_search](http://www.php.net/array_search) by buddel:

```
function recursive_array_search($needle,$haystack) {
    foreach($haystack as $key=>$value) {
        $current_key=$key;
        if($needle===$value OR (is_array($value) && recursive_array_search($needle,$value) !== false)) {
            return $current_key;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```